# Supress comments in output of "gcc -E" preprocessed code

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

For a simple C program I did `gcc -E hello.c -o hello.pp` to see how the program looks after preprocessing.

In the output file I can see many lines which start with `#`, that look like comment. What are these lines?

How can I see only the **C** code, without those comments?

Below is a snippet:

```
user $ gcc -E hello.c -o hello.pp
user $ tail -n 15 hello.pp

extern int ftrylockfile (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) ;

extern void funlockfile (FILE *__stream) __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__));
# 943 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4

# 3 "hello.c" 2
int main() 
{
     printf("Hello world \n");

     return 0;
}
user $
```

Comment: Voting to reopen because of the original question of *"How can I see only the C code, without those comments?"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"How can I see only the C code, without those comments ?"*

You can use `gcc` with options `-E -P` to get rid of the `#` lines of the preprocessor output.

From `gcc` [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

> -P
>
> Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor. This might be useful when running the preprocessor on something that is not C code, and will be sent to a program which might be confused by the linemarkers.